# Reading and writing a tuple to file (numpy.random.RandomState.get_state)

Tags: python, io, tuples

I am trying to save the state of the random number generator in my code to file, to then later read it back in. The tuple generated is of the form:

tuple(str, ndarray of 624 uints, int, int, float)

The returned tuple has the following items:

1. the string ‘MT19937’.
2. a 1-D array of 624 unsigned integer keys.
3. an integer pos.
4. an integer has_gauss.
5. a float cached_gaussian.

Is there a simple way to write this to file, then read it back in in the format it was originally generated?

This is what I have so far:

```
 fx = open('state.dat', 'w')
 fx.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in state) + '\n')
 fx.close()
```

This does print to file, but I am unsure how to convert the string output back into the original format.

Many thanks

Ryan

Comment: why don't use pickle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to save any object on disk as binary:

```
import numpy
import pickle

RANDOM_STATE_FILE = 'random.bin'

def save_random_state():
    with open(RANDOM_STATE_FILE, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(numpy.random.RandomState.get_state(), f)

def load_random_state():
    with open(RANDOM_STATE_FILE, 'rb') as f:
        numpy.random.RandomState.set_state(pickle.load(f))
```